# Telerik RadGrid how to display confirmation message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have  `<telerik:RadGrid/>`
  inside this grid i have the following column contains button

```
   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete"  runat="server" Text="Delete"
```

`CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>' OnCommand="btnDelete_Command">`

```
 protected void btnDelete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem item = gvAllDocuments.Items[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())];
        string FileName = item["documentFileName"].Text;       
    }
```

how I can add confirmation message before function btnDelete_Command executing ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use **ItemIndex**. It is just a row index of the grid. Instead, you want to set unique id inside **DataKeyNames**.

Ideally, you do not want to implement your own delete button, because telerik already has delete button which calls **OnDeleteCommand** automatically.

It is a prefer way of doing it for RadGrid.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ... OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid_DeleteCommand">
   <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="xxxId" ...>
      <Columns>
        <telerik:GridButtonColumn 
            ButtonType="ImageButton" 
            ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete?"
            CommandName="Delete" 
            ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png" 
            Text="Click to delete" UniqueName="Delete">
         </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
      </Columns>
      ...
   </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>

protected void RadGrid_DeleteCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
   int id = Convert.ToInt32(
      e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["xxxId"]);

   // Delete logic here.
}
```

Comment: <Columns>
                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" Visible="false"></telerik:GridBoundColumn> how i can set DataKeyValues for id

Comment: You can set it at `<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id" ...>`. Please make sure that it is **unique** in your database table. You can read more [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/defining-structure/radgrid-and-mastertableview-difference)

Comment: I use Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
         int DocumentId = int.Parse(item["id"].Text);